# How to click a edit button when its defined under repeated similar ids

Tags: cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit, cucumber-jvm

I have a page where many edit buttons are there. And each button have same id i.e enable_edit_content . How to click a specific button  .

This is the code where i have to click

```
<div class="sub-controls" id="motion_eligibility_entry-subcontrols">
<button class="btnedit" **id="enable_edit_content"** name="button" type="button"></button>
<input class="btnsave submit_form" id="save_motions_eligibility_entry" name="commit" 
 type="submit" value="" disabled="disabled">
<button class="btnkill" id="cancel_content" name="button" type="button" 
 disabled="disabled"></button>
</div>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.
I have tried but could not get my results :-

```
 1)   page.all(:css, '#enable_edit_content').each_with_index do |el, i|
           i += 1
           if i == 3
                     el.click
           end
        end
 2)find(:xpath, "//div[@id='motion_eligibility_entry-subcontrols']/button[1]").click
```

Comment: How do you differentiate the buttons manually? Or do you always want to click the button based on index?

Answer (score 0):

you can also scope down your css selector with a within block.

```
within('.sub-controls) do 
  page.find('#enable_edit_content).click
end
```

Because of this very issue, I'd highly recommend shying away from xpath and use css selectors instead!

Hope this helps.